# ElasticSearch: bool/term search is NOT case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

The following ElasticSearch query gives expected result:

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'bool': {'should': [{'term': {'name.keyword': 'Finding'}}]}}]}}, 'size': 10, 'from': 0}
```

but this one give empty result.

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'bool': {'should': [{'term': {'name.keyword': 'finding'}}]}}]}}, 'size': 10, 'from': 0}
```

The only different was that "Finding" changed to "finding". ElasticSearch is "case insensitive" by default, and I have the following mapping. I expected both query give me the same result. What's wrong here?

```
  "name": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "keyword",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) returns exact documents contained in the field. It does not analyze the term that is being searched.

1. In the first case, you are using a [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) (`name.keyword`). This will tokenize `Finding` into `Finding`. So when you use term query to search for `Finding`, this will return you the document containing the exact term `Finding`
2. In the second case, you are querying upon `name` field. Elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. So, here `Finding` gets tokenized to `finding`.

Now, if you search for `finding` using term query you will not get any search result. Since there is no document in the index that have a document containing `"name":"finding"`

---

**From 7.10 elasticsearch has introduced a new parameter [`case_insensitive`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-field-params), which allows us to do case insensitive searches.**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": {
        "value": "finding",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are using Elasticsearch version below 7.10.0, then you should use [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for full-text search